# Exception by using basic functionality (e.g. overallpagenumber) in VB.net Report

Tags: vb.net, exception, dll, report

I will create reports ([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms252067.aspx)) in my VB.net-Application (VS2015). For that I bind some own objects/classes as datasource to the local-report. I also insert these classes as datasource in the RDLC-Report. Then I use the data of these classes in the report, e.g. in a table or textbox. When I start my application and create the report. All works fine. The data from my instance of the class are placed in the report. Great!
(PS: The used class are inside in a separate DLL, written by my own.)

Then I will make my report a little bit nicer. I add a header and place a textbox with the current page number there. (Drag'n'Drop from Report-Data-View)
After that I want to restart my app, but I get an error. I delete the textbox >> no error. I insert the textbox with the "overpagenumber" again >> error!

But the error said: That he can not find my DLL(=S88Model). (errormessage is translated)

> Error loading the code module: 'S88Model, version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Details: The file or assembly
>   "S88Model, Version=1.0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" or
>   a dependency on it was not found. The system cannot find the specified
>   file.

I checked my DLL. All right, the link is my app. Also the file in the "Bin/Debug/" directory.

How can help me?

PS: I create a new app with a report and only the "pagenumber" and it works.

PS:  Here is a part of my code:

```
Public Function ShowReport(ByRef pViewer As ReportViewer, pObj As Object) As Boolean

pViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
Dim locReport As LocalReport = pViewer.LocalReport
Dim parameterListe As New List(Of ReportParameter)


Select Case pObj.GetType
    Case GetType(S88Model.Items.CEmType)

        Dim emType As S88Model.Items.CEmType = pObj
        locReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "TechEditor.ReportEmType.rdlc"
        Dim bs As New Windows.Forms.BindingSource()
        bs.DataSource = emType

        Dim reportdatasource As New ReportDataSource()
        reportdatasource.Name = "EmTypeDataSet"
        reportdatasource.Value = bs

        Dim bs2 As New Windows.Forms.BindingSource()
        bs2.DataSource = CProjectData.DefaultData
        Dim reportdatasource2 As New ReportDataSource()
        reportdatasource2.Name = "ProjectDataSet"
        reportdatasource2.Value = bs2


        locReport.DataSources.Add(reportdatasource)
        locReport.DataSources.Add(reportdatasource2)
        pViewer.RefreshReport()

        ...
```

Comment: Error message is that it cannot find your dll, *or a dependency*.  I'd recommend using the .NET tools to figure out what is failing to load.  The log viewer is fuslogvw, I don't remember offhand if it also configures logging or if you'll need to use another tool for that.  In any event, using your favorite internet search engine on "fuslogvw" should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I execute "fuslogvw.exe" and the protocol-logger is started. But I see no entry. After recompile, too. This may be because my "Execution/Error" comes directly during compiling and _not_ during runtime. (And only, when I insert a standard text like "totalpages" and not a control of these assembly)

Comment: Are all components using the same .NET framework version?  I recently ran into an issue where I was getting surprising compile failures, and it was because one library was set to use an earlier .NET framework version.

Comment: I use in my application and in the DLL ".Net Framework 4.5". In my application I registered also the libaries "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common" (10.0) and "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms" (12.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create an other report. The new report is working (external DLL + Standard-Variablen).

After that I checked my first report, where I get errors at compiling. I looked into the XML of the report. At the end of the xml-file there are some lines like "codemodel", where my DLL was linked. **After I deleted the complete "CodeModel"-Tag in the XML I get no error.** And it works. Now I have only DLL-Link-Information in the "DataSetInfo"-Tag of the xml-file.

I do not why, but it runs now. Thanks @Craig for support.